# Symfony - Unable to add image in an email

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I am working on a cron job and trying to send email using SwiftMailer

Inside the cron `Action` I am using `foreach` loop to iterate through the loop and sending emails to user.

```
foreach($hostDinners as $key => $hostDinner) {
    //generate email
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject("This is a demo subject")
    ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'))
    ->setTo($key)

    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'AppBundle:emails:cron-job-request-and-invitations.html.twig',
            array(
            'dinners' => $hostDinner
            )
        )
    )
    ->setContentType('text/html');
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);


}
```

I am then passing array to the email template as well and inside the email i am using the loop again to display the email content. Everything works fine except that I am unable to display the images.

```
{% for dinner in dinners %}
<img style="display: block;" src="{{ absolute_url(asset('uploads/' ~ dinner.guest_profile_image)) }}" alt="image1" class="section-img" height="auto" width="128">
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**

When I dump the image variable `dinner.guest_profile_image` this is what i get `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/42c5681b253c4dc6a1d145f744e6c3cd.jpeg` and if i access it directly on browser i can see the image i need the email to display.

The `$message` dump is pretty huge since there is alot of css and html in it so i here is the screenshot of the dump where the image tag is

[image]

What am i missing here? What do i need to do to get the images to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `asset_url`

```
<img style="display: block;" src="{{ asset_url('uploads/' ~ dinner.guest_profile_image) }}" alt="...">
```

or you can try embedding your images in `base64` like this:

```
<img style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....(this represent the base64 of your image)..." alt="..."/>
```

**UPDATE 1**

---

```
foreach($hostDinners as $key => $hostDinner) {

    //Encode img in base64
    foreach ($hostDinner as &$item) {
        $path = $item['guest_profile_image']; //use symfony2 functions to get the abs upload path
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        $item["guest_profile_image"] = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    }
    unset($item); // break the reference with the last element

    //generate email
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject("This is a demo subject")
        ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'))
        ->setTo($key)

        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'AppBundle:emails:cron-job-request-and-invitations.html.twig',
                array(
                'dinners' => $hostDinner
                )
            )
        )
        ->setContentType('text/html');
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

and in the view:

```
{% for dinner in dinners %}
      <img style="display: block;" src="{{ dinner.guest_profile_image }}" alt="image..." class="section-img" height="auto" width="128"/>
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE 2**

---

In this line `$item["guest_profile_image"] = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);` you have everything you need to put in the attribute `src` of the `img` tag (you can see in the view I only print print the content of the array `src="{{ dinner.guest_profile_image }}"`). The `alt` attribute is used to html's good practices, but it isn't necessary [alt attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp).

**Official PHP documentation of &**: In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede `$value` with `&`. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

So, in the loop, I'm replacing the image paths from your array to each `base64` codification. In this way you don't have to modify anything in your code, your array have the same size than before, but instead of have the image paths in the array... you have your images decode in base64 in those positions of the array.
More information about & in [Oficial php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Take look (base64 on img tag) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme]

I wish this explanation can help you.

Comment: i tried with `asset_url` that does not seem to work either, i am not sure about `base64` could you please elborate that

Comment: Hi, I am going through this now, sorry i never worked with base64 concept before, can you please let me know if i need to put anything inside `alt` attribute or `img` tag

Comment: why is there an `&` sign inside the `foreach` loop